# Template not updating when controller property changes

Tags: ember.js

Caveat: This is part of my first ember app.

I have an `Ember.MutableArray` on a controller. The corresponding view has an observer that attempts to rerender the template when the array changes. All the changes on the array (via user interaction) work fine. The template is just never updated. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Ember 1.2.0 and Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.7af6fcb0, though I guess the latter shouldn't matter for this.

Here is the code:

```js
var ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this._super();
    var topicsController = this.controllerFor('topics');
    var topicFilterController = this.controllerFor('topic_filter');
    this.render('topics', {outlet: 'topics', controller: topicsController, into: 'application'});
    this.render('topic_filter', {outlet: 'topic_filter', controller: topicFilterController, into: 'application'});
  },
});

module.exports = ApplicationRoute;


var TopicFilterController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  topicFilters: Ember.A([ ]),
  areTopicFilters: function() {
    console.log('topicFilters.length -> ' + this.topicFilters.length);
    return this.topicFilters.length > 0;
  }.property('topicFilters'),
  getTopicFilters: function() {
    console.log('getTopicFilters....');
    return this.store.findByIds('topic', this.topicFilters);
  }.property('topicFilters'),
  actions: {
    addTopicFilter: function(t) {
      if(this.topicFilters.indexOf(parseInt(t)) == -1) {
        this.topicFilters.pushObject(parseInt(t));
      }
      // this.topicFilters.add(parseInt(t));
      console.log('topicFilters -> ' + JSON.stringify(this.topicFilters));
    },
    removeTopicFilter: function(t) {
      this.topicFilters.removeObject(parseInt(t));
      console.log('topicFilters -> ' + JSON.stringify(this.topicFilters));
    }
  }
});

module.exports = TopicFilterController;


var TopicFilterView = Ember.View.extend({
  topicFiltersObserver: function() {
    console.log('from view.... topicFilters has changed');
    this.rerender();
  }.observes('this.controller.topicFilters.[]')
});

module.exports = TopicFilterView;


// topic_filter.hbs
{{#if areTopicFilters}}
  <strong>Topic filters:</strong>
  {{#each getTopicFilters}}
    <a {{bind-attr href='#'}} {{action 'removeTopicFilter' id}}>{{topic}}</a>
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}


var TopicsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['topicFilter'],
  all_topics: function() {
    return this.store.find('topic');
  }.property('model', 'App.Topic.@each'),
  actions: {
    addTopicFilter: function(t) {
      App.__container__.lookup('controller:topicFilter').send('addTopicFilter', t);
    }
  }
});

module.exports = TopicsController;


// topics.hbs
<ul class="list-group list-unstyled">
  {{#each all_topics}}
    <li class="clear list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">{{entryCount}}</span>
      <a {{bind-attr href="#"}} {{action 'addTopicFilter' id}}>{{topic}}</a>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

your observes should just be `controller.topicFilters.[]`

And honestly this is a very inefficient way of doing this, rerendering your entire view because a single item changed on the array.  If you show your template I can give you a much better way of handling this.

Here's an example, I've changed quite a few things, and guessed on some others since I don't know exactly how your app is.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uFIMekOJ/1/edit

Comment: Changing the observes on topicFiltersObserver in TopicFilterView unfortunately did not make any difference.
I have added my templates at the end of the code above. This is my first Ember app, so much of this is trial and error on my part. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Will you add the topic filter template also

Comment: It is there, above TopicsController.

Comment: I'll set up a jsbin, it'll take a bit to setup the fixture data.

Comment: Fantastic. I've been playing with it on and off today, but to no avail. Thanks again.

Comment: I tossed a jsbin in the answer, feel free to play with it and do what you will.